# The application is crashed by CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I'm developing application and it uses CoreData.

But it crashes the application when I push AddNewObject's done button.

[image: iPhone screens]

MasterViewController.m

```
...

- (void)addNewCountdown:(NSString*)title date:(NSDate*)date main:(BOOL)main notification:(BOOL)notification notificationDate:(NSInteger)notificationDate
{
    [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    [newManagedObject setValue:title forKey:@"title"];

    [newManagedObject setValue:date forKey:@"date"];

    [newManagedObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:notification] forKey:@"notification"];

    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}

...

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

...
```

NewObjectViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender
{
    ...
    else{
        NSIndexPath *indexPath_two = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
        DatePickerCell *cell_two = (DatePickerCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath_two];

        [cell_two.timer invalidate];

        NSLog(@"Text:%@",text);

        if ([cell_two.timer isValid] == YES) {
            NSLog(@"timer yes");
        }

        MasterViewController *master =  [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        [master addNewCountdown:text
                           date:cell_2.DatePicker.date main:cell_3.mainSwitch.on
                   notification:cell_4.mainSwitch.on notificationDate:_beforeMinute];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

And here's log.

```
it happens when I push done button.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Event''
```

Why did it happen?

What can I do?

Please tell me an answer.

And please add a comment if you want to know something else.

Comment: *"Why did it happen?"* The error message clearly says that the managed object context is nil when it shouldn't be. - *"What can I do?"* Use the debugger, set breakpoints and step through your code. Check where/if the context is set etc ...

Comment: At minimum you should tell on which line exactly the exception occurs. - And what is `[self managedObjectContext]` for ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some break points in to step through and check variable values. I would start with the fetchedResultsManager accessor, specifically the line:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Check that your managedObjectContext property is not nil. Also check that your managed object model has an entity named Event (pay attention to spelling and capitalization). These are the kind of things your error message is indicating.

It would help to know what line the exception occurs on. Go to breakpoints navigator pane on left and press the '+' button at the bottom. Choose to Add Exception Break. This will stop the debugger at the point that the exception occurs and you can check the relevant variable values for clues.

Another thing I would think about is your need for caching the fetchedResults. I have seen issues before where the cache is stale and weird crashes commenced. By any chance does it succeed the first time and crash thereafter? I usually flush the cache before creating a new instance:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // flush cache before creating new frc
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    ...
```

I may be wrong but I don't believe you get any worthwhile benefit from caching the results unless you really are working with huge datasets and processing. I usually leave cache nil and see no issues with scrolling.